# I tried setting up a greenscreen removal process with this blender tutorial but it didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: chromakey

Here is the tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lA6AuZYbLyQ

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Used the droppler key, and nothing.

[image]

Comment: Try Ctrl+Shift+Click on Keying to move the viewer node.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you connect the Viewer node to the output of Keying, you should see proper results. Otherwise you're viewing the pre-keyed result.

[image]

[image]  You may have to refresh the image in the compositor by clicking and releasing the down arrow to the left of the "Untitled.2" selection.